# I am trying to read a json payload from a file and setting the values from CSV file using scenario outline and examples

Tags: karate

I have a sample json file as below

```
{
book : {bookId : '<bookId>' , 
         bookName : '<bookName>'
         },
staff : {
     sfattid : '<sfattid>',
     name : '<name>'
     },
libraryMember : { 
libMembId : '<libMembId>',
name : '<libraryMember>'

         }
}
```

I have a csv file with below information

[image]

I want to set the values for each variable from csv file and set the REST request 3 times during run time .

Feature: scenario outline using a dynamic table
    from a csv file

```
Scenario Outline: staffname name: <name>
  # When json payload =     {book : {bookId : '<bookId>' , bookName : '<bookName>',},staff : {sfattid : '<sfattid>', name : '<name>'},libraryMember : { libMembId : '<libMembId>' ,name : '<libraryMember>'}}
    When json payload = read("request.json")
    Given url 'http://localhost:8089/'
    And path 'returnBook'
    And request payload
    When method post
    Then status 200
    Then match karate.jsonPath(response,"$.status") ==  '<status>'



Examples:
| read('bookreturn.csv') |
```

I have wrote below code which works perfectly but in below case the same json payload is present in feature file which I want to keep in a text file .Please suggest some code .

Feature: scenario outline using a dynamic table
    from a csv file

```
Scenario Outline: staffname name: <name>
  # When json payload =     {book : {bookId : '<bookId>' , bookName : '<bookName>',},staff : {sfattid : '<sfattid>', name : '<name>'},libraryMember : { libMembId : '<libMembId>' ,name : '<libraryMember>'}}
    When json payload = read("request.json")
    Given url 'http://localhost:8089/'
    And path 'returnBook'
    And request payload
    When method post
    Then status 200
    Then match karate.jsonPath(response,"$.status") ==  '<status>' 

    Examples:
    | read('bookreturn.csv') |
```

Comment: @hackernoon.com/@ptrthomas can you please help me with above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, you can't optimize this any further because for `<name>` to work it *has* to be *within* the feature file itself. Personally I think you are un-necessarily trying to over-engineer your tests. There is nothing wrong with what you have already.

If you really insist - here is the alternative, refer: https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-features

```
* def books = read('bookreturn.csv')
* def result = call read('called.feature') books
```

But you will need to use 2 feature files. Each book in the loop can be used in [embedded expressions](https://github.com/intuit/karate#embedded-expressions). So you can read from a JSON file, and any embedded expressions in the file will work.

Just stick to what you have, seriously !